# I am trying to get the output as below ..I have one table called A and another table called B,

Tags: sql, unpivot

```
TABLE A

ID PartNo Qty
----------------
1  A123   10
2  A123   15

TABLE B

ID   A_ID   Service
------------------------
1    1      XYZ
2    2      XYZ
```

Expected results

TABLE C

```
Column Name   ColumnValue   Val_Count
--------------------------------------
PartNo         A123            2
QTY             10             1
Qty             15             1
Service         XYZ            2
```

Please help, I tried PIVOT but not getting the output.

```
SELECT partno AS PartNo, [10], [15] 
FROM (SELECT qnty, partNo FROM PartInfo) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT ( Count(qnty) FOR qnty IN ([10], [15]) ) AS PivotTable 
group by partNo, [10],[15]
```

Comment: _"I tried PIVOT but not getting the output."_ Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
with ab as (
      select a.partno, a.qty, b.srv
      from a join
           b
           on a.id = b.a_id
     )
select 'partno' as name, partno as value, count(*)
from ab
group by partno
union all
select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(255)), count(*)
from ab
group by qty
select 'service', service, count(*)
from ab
group by service;
```

There may be simpler methods, depending on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need unpivoting instead of pivoting. One option to figure this out would be applying `UNION ALL` in the subselect, and then aggregating by derived columns in the main query :

```
SELECT [Column Name], [Column Value], COUNT(*) as [Val_Count]
FROM
(
 SELECT 'PartNo' as [Column Name], [PartNo] as [Column Value] FROM tableA A
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Service', [Service] FROM tableB B
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Qty', cast([Qty] as varchar) FROM tableA
) A2
GROUP BY [Column Name], [Column Value]
ORDER BY [Column Name], [Column Value];

Column Name Column Value Val_Count
----------- ------------ ---------
PartNo      A123         2
Qty         10           1
Qty         15           1
Service     XYZ          2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ebf1defe026e429d05b5eb61493a5f3)</kbd>